# Crashing app due to null string added to dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

```
func addSongToQueue(){
        let post = [
            "data": [
                "QueueId": MyViewState.selectedQueId,
                "track":[
                    [
                        "title":selectedTrack.title,
                        "stream_url":  selectedTrack.stream_url,
                        "userName"  :  selectedTrack.userName,
                        "artWorkURL":  selectedTrack.artWorkURL,
                        "userAvatar":  selectedTrack.userAvatar,
                        "trackID"   :  selectedTrack.trackID,
                        "duration"  :  selectedTrack.duration
                    ]]]
        ]
```

Tracks Getting Code :

```
-(instancetype) initWithDictionary: (NSDictionary*) SCTrackDict {
    self = [self init];
    if (self) {
        self.title = SCTrackDict[@"title"];
        self.stream_url = SCTrackDict[@"stream_url"];
        self.userDict = SCTrackDict[@"user"];
        self.userName = self.userDict[@"username"];
        self.artWorkURL = SCTrackDict[@"artwork_url"];
        self.trackID = SCTrackDict[@"id"];
        self.userAvatar = self.userDict[@"avatar_url"];
        self.duration = SCTrackDict[@"duration"];

    }
    return self;
}
```

Parsing Data into Tracks :

```
+(NSMutableArray *) parseJSONData: (NSData *) JSONData {
    NSError* error;
    NSMutableArray* SCTrackArray = [NSMutableArray new];

    NSArray *JSONArray= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONData options:0 error: &error];
    if ([JSONArray isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        for (NSDictionary* trackDict in JSONArray) {
            SCTrack* trackObject = [[SCTrack alloc]initWithDictionary:trackDict];
            //Need to print out trackDict to see JSON dictionary
            [SCTrackArray addObject:trackObject];
        }
    }
    return SCTrackArray;
}
```

How can I add "" (empty string) if NSNull is there and also crashing on `trackid` as it is long value.

Is it possible to modify this code without checking individual key before adding in dict?

Comment: use trackID as optional.

Comment: can you please add code how to use optional ?

Comment: show me the code how you access `trackID` I will write then alternate code for it.

Comment: Updated Question with all code

Comment: What language are you actually using?

Comment: SCTrack class for getting track array is written in Obj-c other all in swift2

Answer (score 0):

Clarify to yourself: What action do you want to take if a key that you expect is not present, or is [NSNull null], or is an empty string, or is a dictionary when you expected a string and so on and so on.

Once you've explained that to yourself, you write the code accordingly. It seems at the moment your code follows the rule "If it's not there, I'll crash".

Comment: [NSNull null] crashing app

Answer (score 0):

before adding an object just check like this that is this null or not

```
if(yourObject isEqual:(id)[NSNUll null])
{
    // Then do nothing
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like this:

```
"stream_url":  selectedTrack.stream_url != nul ? selectedTrack.stream_url : @"";
```

Hope it help.

You can read about **Ternary operation**

Comment: What's not working? Maybe you have more bugs than just one and now it crashes on the next one? What exactly happened?

Comment: Shorter: selectedTrack.stream_url ?: @""